# Can I install Windows from a preexisting Windows installation?

Tags: bootcamp, windows, ssd

I have an early 2011 Macbook Pro. The Superdrive broke, so I installed an SSD and put my old HDD in an optibay. The old HDD had a bootcamp Windows installation on it. Since I can't use bootcamp without a Superdrive, is it possible to install Windows on my SSD from within my HDD installation of Windows? Or do I need to do the installation through bootcamp?

Thanks.

Comment: why can't you use bootcamp without a superdrive? btw, I've never had my bootcamp partition on the same drive as my Mac boot - maybe see if Windows is still bootable as-is.

Comment: Apple's firmware prevents booting off of USB unless your computer didn't come with a superdrive to begin with (e.g. macbook air, retina).

Comment: ahh, didn't realise - must have used the superdrive when I did mine - was some time ago. Try this… http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1680652 I've just ordered a bunch of new USB sticks so I'll be testing it too later in the week ;)

Comment: This tutorial allows you to create the bootable disk, but not actually boot off of it.

Comment: did you read it all?

Comment: Yes. There is discussion in the comments over how USBs are not bootable.